# Free C compilers for XA / SmartXA / SmartXA2 based controllers. Are any?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, embedded, controller, microcontroller

We are developing a protection part for a Philips NXP SmartXA2 based dongle. It supports 2 modes of operation: 8051 compatible VM (8-bit) and a SmartXA2 (16-bit) mode. I already used SDCC for 8051 mode development. But I wish not to stick to 8-bit! The Raisonance Kit has support for 16-bit XA mode, but it is commercial. I wonder if there any free C compilers out there that support XA / SmartXA2 based controllers? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best I can determine, the answer is "No, there aren't any."

Philips only mentions Raisonance as the only available compiler for SmartXA2.  I can find no evidence online that anyone provides a GCC port for it, and that would be the only other likely suspect beyond what's officially supported.

Oddly, there is one mention on a resume at http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~gskc/cv.html of IBM working on a GCC port (see the author's "employment" section for 2003, apparently as a summer internship), but I see no evidence that anything came of that effort, so I'd have to conclude it was never completed.